# To get R1C1 notation from A1 notation in google spreadsheet using GAS

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I need to get the range address in R1 C1 notation given the A1 notation. I found no built in formula which can do it.
i.e.
If I pass A3:C8 then the output should be 3 1 8 3 in r1c1 notation

```
function getRangeAddress() {
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
    var range = sheet.getActiveRange()
    if (range) var rangeAddress = range.getA1Notation();
    else var rangeAddress = sheet.getActiveRange().getA1Notation();
    return rangeAddress;
}

converttoR1C1(rangeAddress);
```

Comment: Duplicate of [How to get Row & Column values from A1Notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30112522/how-to-get-row-column-values-from-a1notation)

Answer (score 5):

We could use [ADDRESS](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093308?hl=en) to get the R1C1 address. As it requires the row and column indexes we could use ROW, COLUMN, ROWS and COLUMNS to get the corresponding indexes.

The following formula will return the R1C1 address of the cell holding the formula

```
=ADDRESS(ROW(),COLUMN(),1,FALSE)
```

In some other scenarios we could need the R1C1 by using Google Apps Script, in this we could use getRow and getColumn to get the start cell indexes. The use getNumRows and getNumColumns and calculate the corresponding indexes for the end cell.

Example:

```
function toR1C1(reference) {
  var range = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(reference);
  var row = range.getRow();
  var column = range.getColumn();
  var start = 'R' + row + 'C' + column;
  var rows = range.getNumRows();
  var columns = range.getNumColumns();
  var end = ((rows * columns) == 1)?'':':R' + (row + rows - 1) + 'C' + (column + columns - 1);
  return start + end;
}
```

Comment: Just for observers, the result will be something like `R1C3:R1C17`

Answer (score 1):

You could use an associative array as sort of a lookup table.

var Alpha2Numeric = {A:1,B:2,C:3....} then it's just a matter of reversing the strings on each side of the colon and converting the letters to numbers with Alpha2Numeric[CapitalLetter]